# chisq.test in R

Tags: r

test()` in Rand it gives me back the x-squared and the p-value.

Now I want to take the p-value and according to the reading proceed with my program. How can I extract the p-value from the result of the output of `chisq.test()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
chisq.test(x)$p.value
```

You can see what an object holds using `str`:

```
str(chisq.test(x))
```

Comment: `str()` can be a little unwieldy for my tastes. I generally prefer `attributes()` for this purpose.

Comment: `names()` is another decent option here too.

Answer (score 3):

Performing a \Chi^2 test on the vectors x and y and storing it in 'results'

```
results<-chisq.test(x,y)
```

you can then retrieve the estimated parameters as

```
results[1], results[3], ... or results$statistic, results$p.value, ...
```

where the last part is of course the most self-describing way to do it.

Remember to cast the results to numeric values, that is

```
as.numeric(results[1])
```

HTH,

Christian

Comment: casting to numeric is not necessary, as they are numeric already.